# create symlinks by dropping version number

Tags: shell-script, awk, symlink, ln

I have large number of shared libraries like this:

```
libexpat.so.1.6.7                        libqquicklayoutsplugin.so        libstdc++.so.6.0.24
libexportlib.so.1.0.0                    libqsvg.so                       libsystemd.so.0.19.0
libfontconfig.so.1.10.1                  libQt53DAnimation.so.5.11.3      libwidgetsplugin.so
libfreetype.so.6.16.0                    libQt53DCore.so.5.11.3           libwindowplugin.so
libgcc_s.so.1                            libQt53DExtras.so.5.11.3         libX11.so.6.3.0
libgcrypt.so.20.2.2                      libQt53DInput.so.5.11.3          libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
```

I'm trying to loop over all my shared libraries and create sym-links by dropping their version number (if they have any version number). For example:

```
libgcrypt.so.20.2   -> libgcrypt.so.20.2.2
libgcrypt.so.20     -> libgcrypt.so.20.2.2
libgcrypt.so        -> libgcrypt.so.20.2.2
```

---

So far I have tried to find all shared libraries with version number with:

```
find . -name '*.so.*'
```

But I cannot figure out how to use `awk` and `ln -s` commands:

```
find . -name '*.so.*' -exec #awk and ln -s commands goes here# \;
```

Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really seems to be the job of something else (`ldconfig`?), but:

```
find . -name '*.so.*' -exec sh -c '
for so; do
  target="${so%.*}"
  while [ "${target##*.}" != "$target" ]; do
    echo ln -s "$so" "$target"
    target="${target%.*}"
  done
done' _ {} +
```

The shell command loops over arguments (the filenames), and for each filename, strips off extensions to get link targets (until the target has no extension, after the `.so` gets stripped off). Remove the `echo` to actually make the links.